# OpenSSL rsa decryption don't work with the same c-string

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl

I'm trying to make a file checker program that fetch enrypted hash from a JSON file. I'm using Qt and OpenSSL so its a mix of C/C++. I have succeeded in fetching encrypted hash but when I tried to derypt them it don't work however when I encrypt it direcly in the same program it work even if the to string are equals.

As with this code :

```cpp
void RSAFileCheckerInfoFetcher::decrypt() 
{

    char *key = "Public Key";

    RSA * publicKey = nullptr;
    BIO *keybio;
    keybio = BIO_new_mem_buf(key, -1);
    publicKey  = PEM_read_bio_RSA_PUBKEY(keybio, &publicKey, NULL, NULL);

    RSA * privateKey = nullptr;
    FILE * fp = fopen("path to private key", "rb");//making a private key to test
    privateKey = PEM_read_RSAPrivateKey(fp, &privateKey, NULL, NULL);;

    char *plainText = "puMcJaBzbovqZPaaLC4jxw==";//the first hash i have in the JSON file
    unsigned char decrypted[400];
    char encrypted2[400]; //reencrypt to test

    QByteArray encryptedHash = encryptedHashes.first();
    char  encrypted [400]; //encrypted hash
    strcpy(encrypted, encryptedHash.data());//encryptedHash.data():encrypted hash from JSON


    //encrypt to test
    int encrypted_length = RSA_private_encrypt(strlen(plainText), reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(plainText), reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(encrypted2), privateKey, 1);
    if (encrypted_length == -1)
    {
        exit(0);
    }

    printf("Encrypted text =%s\n", encrypted);
    printf("Encrypted length =%d\n", encrypted_length);

    //decrypt the encrypted hash from the JSON file
    int decrypted_length = RSA_public_decrypt(encrypted_length, reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(encrypted), decrypted, publicKey, 1);//Je déchiffre le hash obtenue à partir du fichier JSON
    if (decrypted_length == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "Don't work" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Decrypted Text =%s\n", decrypted);
        printf("Decrypted Length =%d\n", decrypted_length);
    }

    //decrypt encrypted hash to test
    decrypted_length = RSA_public_decrypt(encrypted_length, reinterpret_cast<unsigned char *>(encrypted2), decrypted, publicKey, 1);//Dechiffre le hash chiffré pour le test
    if (decrypted_length == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "Don't work" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Decrypted Text =%s\n", decrypted);
        printf("Decrypted Length =%d\n", decrypted_length);
    }
    if (strcmp(encrypted, encrypted2) == 0)
        std::cout << "encrypted = encrypted2" << std::endl;
}
```

The output is :
`

```
Encrypted text =<)qO¬þ¬║âcê9lmiÑß1+p²÷!â}j¾8
Encrypted length =128
Don't work
Decrypted Text =puMcJaBzbovqZPaaLC4jxw==
Decrypted Length =24
encrypted = encrypted2
```

`

Comment: Your code is a big mess, with all kinds of buffers being created at bad positions etc. Please clean that up before posting. What are you actually trying to accomplish? Why are you using low level signature generation operations in the first place?

Comment: I would like no one to be able to replace the server with another one to prevent someone from giving a fake JSON file because if he could change his client. And what is the high level signature ?

Comment: [EVP](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Signing_and_Verifying)! Note that there is no shame in signing hashes either, if that's your worry (but I'm guessing here).

Comment: Okay, thanks to you. I'm going to go on the EVP. And sorry for the title, I was in a hurry.